# Nikon D3100 off-camera TTL wireless flash: which Yongnuo flash / controller?

Tags: off-camera-flash, nikon-d3100, wireless-flash

I have a Nikon D3100 camera, and I'd like a flash setup that I can use off-camera, that takes advantage of the camera's iTTL feature and that doesn't depend on its popup flash. I'm considering using a Yongnuo YN-622N controller in the hotshoe and a Yongnuo YN-568EX flash unit off-camera in TTL mode.

Does anyone know if this will work, or of any alternative units that would give me what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably be better off using a [YN-622N-TX](http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-yn-622n-tx-for-nikon-now-available/) dedicated transmitter on the camera. It has a small LCD screen so you can see what your settings are all at once. The YN-622N only has a few LEDs to indicate a lot of different things, and it can be a bit more of a PITA to use than a YN-622N transceiver unit.

If you still want TTL/FP (HSS) and remote power commanding over radio, however, you also should understand that the YN-568EX does NOT have a built-in radio receiver. You will also have to get a YN-622N and attach it to the foot of the flash, as well as having the YN-622N-TX (or another YN-622N) on the camera's hotshoe.

The only flash Yongnuo makes that has a built-in YN-622 receiver is the [YN-685](http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-yn685-speedlite-now-available/), and at this moment, it *only* comes in Canon flavor; and has no optical slave modes at all. Theoretically, it *might* work with a YN-622N-TX, but the only folks who've bought one so far and are reporting about it on the internet are Canon shooters.

There are a number of alternatives you can go for, aside from the Yongnuo flash/trigger combinations, but Yongnuo is probably the cheapest one with a good reputation. You could also look at Phottix's Odin system and their Mitros/Mitros+ flashes (more expensive, but easier to expand and better reliability/build reputation). And, of course, there are the TTL PocketWizards and RadioPoppers if you need pro reliability Sekonic lightmeter integration.

Comment: Thanks so much! Great information. Sounds like I could also use the YN-622N transceiver to control other TTL units such as the 468-II, which I already have?

Comment: I can confirm it does control the YN-468-II flash, after buying a YN-622N-TX / YN-622N kit.